# UIPickerView is not aligned properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uipickerview

I am using a UIPickerView in iOS8 and am having a very strange problem. This is my general implementation:

```
_providerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 344, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:)];
_providerToolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], done];
[self.view addSubview:_providerToolbar];

_providerPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 300, 0, 0)];
_providerPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
_providerPickerView.dataSource = self;
_providerPickerView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:_providerPickerView];
```

This seemed to work perfectly fine in iOS7 but in iOS8, the done button seems to be aligned incorrectly. Why is there no space between the end of the done button and the toolbar border?

[image]

Comment: Don't know what cause it to stop working, but maybe a workaround would be to add another item, after the done button, of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`

Comment: Thats definitely one way to fix it but its super hacky as i would need to turn that on/off based on whether iOS7/iOS8 is running the app